# Typescript error connecting class component to the reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a class component connected to the redux `rootReducer`, but I am getting a TS error on the mapPropsToState part stating: `Property 'unit' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'`

The part that fails on the component (first {unit}) underlined with the error above:

```
export default connect(
  ({ unit }) => ({ unit }),
  { fetchRegisterAll }
)(TabNavUnits);
```

My root reducer seems to be fine:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import auth from './auth'
import person from './person'
import room from './room'
import unit from './unit'
import scenario from './scenario'
import data from './data'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth,
  person,
  room,
  unit,
  scenario,
  data
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out. I need to import the RootState interface and declare the unit to be a type of RootState like so:

```
export default connect(
  ({ unit }: RootState) => ({ unit }),
  { fetchRegisterAll }
)(TabNavUnits);
```

Comment: Yes, see our docs on using TypeScript with React-Redux: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component